# I need FFMPEG command to convert some video files from h.265 to h.264 with Nvidia hardware

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, nvidia-geforce, h.264, h.265

I have a decent Nvidia graphics card, capable of h.265 and h.264 encoding and decoding in hardware (Geforce RTX 2060), running on a Ubuntu installation. I have a whole bunch of video files that I need to convert from h.265 to h.264 (note: yes, I need to downconvert them). Could someone give me an ffmpeg command to convert these, using hardware for all the decoding and encoding?

Comment: As suggested in some other question about video conversion, use Handbrake, a free and open-source front-end.

Comment: Handbrake does NOT use hardware acceleration.

Comment: From [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware Acceleration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#CUDANVENCNVDEC). Full hardware transcode with NVDEC and NVENC: `ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow output` Making comment instead of answer because I do not have the hardware to try it myself.